# How do I draw a rectangle in Pygame?

Tags: rendering, pygame

I am getting the error "*AttributeError: 'Rect' object has no attribute 'draw'*" with this code:

```
import pygame
import sys

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps=30

screen_height = 520
screen_width = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))

class Rect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,width,height,color,value):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.value = value
    def change_value(self,color,value):
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.value=value

rects = pygame.sprite.Group()

rect = Rect(100,100,black,1)
rects.add(rect)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            terminate()

    screen.fill(white)
    rect.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(fps)
```

Why is this?  How do I render a rectangle?

I am trying to render and save 8 rectangles which are clickable to turn them on or off. I am trying to render the rects as objects to later use their collision for mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the `Rect` object doesn't have a `draw` method.  ([Documentation for `Rect` is here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), for reference.)

Perhaps you meant to write—

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, rect, 1)
```

—if you just wanted a rectangle's edge lines like this:

[image]

Or maybe you meant—

```
screen.fill(black, rect)
```

—for a filled rectangle like this:

[image]